# xdebug not working after ubuntu upgrade

Tags: php, eclipse, ubuntu, xdebug

today I upgraded ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 and xdebug is not working anymore. I use eclipse Luna Service Release 2.

I've tried reinstalling xdebug through pecl, apt-get, even manual install following http://xdebug.org/wizard.php instructions (pasting my phpinfo() output).

I have xampp, in `/opt/lampp` directory. 
I've tried several locations for "zend_extension" in `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini` such as `zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so` and `zend_extension =/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so`

When I hit debug on eclipse, the browser receives the order, and the parameters ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY= are included in the url, but the execution will not stop on any breakpoint.

When I run phpinfo() xdebug is not showing as an installed module.

any hints?

I removed the phpinfo() output for clarification after posting the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found no solution, so I had to remove all the lamp package, and I reinstalled everything as independent modules following this tutorial: http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-15-10/, then I did this to install xdebug:

1.- Install xdebug extension for PHP

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug
```

2.- Check the location of "xdebug.so" module, which is kept under "/usr/lib/php5/20131226", where the number depends on the PHP version.

3.- The installation creates a configuration file "/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini" with the following line (otherwise, create one):

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
```

NOTE: in the previous version, you need to specify the full-path filename, e.g., "zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so".
Include the following lines into "xdebug.ini" to enable remote debugging from Eclipse PDT:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
```

Recall that Apache loads PHP configuration files "/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini" and "/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/*.ini". To enable the above xdebug configuration file, create the following symlink in "/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d":

```
$ cd /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
$ sudo ln -s ../../mods-available/xdebug.ini 20-xdebug.ini
$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Sep 11 19:42 20-xdebug.ini -> ../../mods-available/xdebug.ini
```

4.- Check PHP configuration file "/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini" for the following settings:

```
; Turn on the error display for development system, 
; but not for production system.
display_errors = On

; Format error in HTML
html_errors = On
```

5.- Restart the Apache2:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

And it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

For now Xdebug (Please only use uptil Xdebug 2.6, because later versions had some issues with debugging); only work up to php 7.2 (i.e. less than 7.3). So if you had any other version installed like php 7.3 or 7.4 then you had to also install php 7.2 along side your current php version (mostly because now by default latest version is installed through apt). and then update in between alternatives.

To set PHP 7.0 as the default, run

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0
```

To set PHP 7.2 as the default, run

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

To set PHP 7.3 as the default, run

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3
```

To set PHP 7.4 as the default, run

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
```

Before we can configure Apache to use PHP 7.2, we need to disable the new (or old) version of PHP by typing

```
a2dismod php7.4
```

Now enable the newly installed PHP 7.2 version with the following command:

```
a2enmod php7.2
```

Restart the Apache web server for the changes to take effect:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```